# ASP.Net seems to have a design view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, mono

I am using mono in Mint Linux. Its great for C# and Im learning both C# and ASP.NET. I have set up the Apache server to handle ASP.  The trouble is I am so new i have been using MS Visual Studio. With Mono, I cant seem to find the design view page. I have tried adding an item or page but it seems very different to working with Visual studio web developer 2010 or 2013.

I an trying to stay away from windows, everything i do is in Linux. Was Ubuntu but now I use Mint. Can anyone understand what I am talking about. I use the design view a lot in MS ASP.NET Web Developer. Is there a design view to work with using mono ?

Comment: as you add tag asp.net mvc to your question: in MS VS there is no design view for mvc Views. Only markup and razor (for example) expressions.

Comment: a view in mono? I guess you mean monodevelop, right?